# Can't get AngularJS Google Maps to render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am having a hard time getting my Angular Google Maps map to load. It isn't throwing any console errors...

app.module.js

```
(function() {

  angular.module('myplaces', ['ui.router', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'])

}())
```

places.component.js

```
angular.module('myplaces')
  .component('placespage', {
    templateUrl: 'places.template.html',
    controller: controller
  })
  function controller() {
    const ctrl = this;
    ctrl.map = {
        center:
        {
          latitude: -25.363,
          longitude: 131.044
        },
        zoom:7
    };
  }
```

places.template.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Results</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had forgotten to use `$ctrl` to bind to the controller in my template.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='$ctrl.map.center' zoom='$ctrl.map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
```